# Morris Charts Implementation in SharePoint 2013 using REST API

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, morris.js

Is it possible to implement Morris Charts in SharePoint 2013 using Rest API?  If no, how can I implement morris charts to create dashboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        new Morris.Line({
          // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
          element: 'myfirstchart',
          // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
          // the chart.
          data: [
            { year: '2008', value: 20 },
            { year: '2009', value: 10 },
            { year: '2010', value: 5 },
            { year: '2011', value: 5 },
            { year: '2012', value: 20 }
          ],
          // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
          xkey: 'year',
          // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
          ykeys: ['value'],
          // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hover over the
          // chart.
          labels: ['Value']
        });

});

</script>
<div id="myfirstchart" style="height: 250px;"></div>
```

[image]